# Sequence true or false questions

Tags: real-analysis

Which statements are true?

(a) If  {s$_n$} is unbounded then it is true that either
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n=∞ $$ or else $$\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n=-∞ $$

(b) If  {s$_n$} is unbounded then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} |s_n|=∞ $$

(c) If  {s$_n$} and {t$_n$} are both bounded then so is {s$_n$+t$_n$}.

Could we possibly consider using the triangle inequality, and if so how would we go about it

(d) If  {s$_n$} and {t$_n$} are both unbounded then so is {s$_n$+t$_n$}.

(e) If  {s$_n$} and {t$_n$} are both bounded then so is {s$_n$t$_n$}.

(f) If  {s$_n$} and {t$_n$} are both unbounded then so is {s$_n$t$_n$}.

(g) If  {s$_n$} is bounded then so is {$\frac 1s_n$}.

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried so far? For a), does every unbounded sequence have a limit?

Comment: I think the $\infty$ already means the limit does not exist

Comment: No. $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = \infty$ means that for every $N>0$, from some point onwards all terms of the sequence $(s_n)$ are $>N$. To put it more formally, $\forall N >0 \exists n \in \mathbb{N}: m \geq n : s_m > N$. For instance, the sequence $1$, $-2$, $3$, $-4$, $\ldots$ is unbounded but does not have a limit. Same goes for the sequence $1$, $2$, $1$, $3$, $1$, $4$, $1$, $5$, $\ldots$.

Comment: Oh, quite right. Same thing as $\lim_{n \to \infty} \tan n$. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}a)&\;\;s_n=(-1)^nn\\
b)&\;\;\{s_n\}=\{0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,\ldots\}\\
c)&\;\;|s_n+t_n|\le|s_n|+|t_n|\;\;\text {(as you said)}\\
d)&\;\;s_n=n\;,\;\;t_n=-n\\
e)&\;\;|s_nt_n|=|s_n||t_n|\\
f)&\;\;\{s_n\}=\{0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5\ldots\}\;\;,\;\;\{t_n\}=\{1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,\;\ldots\}\\
g)&\;\;s_n=\frac1n\end{align*}$$